# Android Studio scale WebView content to current WebView Size (not full screen WebView)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, webview, android-webview

I've got a WebView that doesn't use the whole screen of my device. I want to scale the shown website to fit in the WebView.

Using 
`webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);`
only scales the WebView content as if it were using the whole screen of my device. So there is still a part cut off.

If someone knows how to solve this problem please let me know.
Thanks, merlinus

Comment: can you add screenshot ?